# Class redefinition c++

Tags: c++, class, extern, redefinition

I have a c++ project which has a class called `A`.
I also have a header file, called `Definitions.h`.

I wrote the following code in the header file:

```
A* aClass;
```

And in the main of the application, I write:

```
aClass = new A();
```

This gives me the redefinition errors of class `A` by the other classes which use it.

So, after searching the web, I found out that the `extern` keyword should be added to the deceleration, so I modified the header file's class deceleration into this:

```
extern A* aClass;
```

Now I'm getting `LNK2001` errors.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give a full code example

Comment: Make it extern by having an additional A* aClass; in a single translation unit (source file)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574403/673730

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to see your code to completely understand where the error might be, but you could try this:

In the header:

```
extern A* aClass;
```

In the main.cc, before the main function:

```
A* aClass;
```

and inside the main function:

```
int main()
{
...
aClass = new A();
...
}
```

Hopefully that helps!